# SQLite: Select table1 columns where table1.columnA != table2.columnA and table2.Date = this month

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want query code for above question.

sample data:
**Customers(table1):**
name       cpuid
john   ABX0001
suneel     ABX0002
james      ABX0003

**Paid(table2):**
name       cpuid     paid  date
john       ABX0001   3000  2016-04-11
james      ABX0003   4000  2016-04-05

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [list] FROM [Table A] A FULL OUTER JOIN [Table B] B ON A.Value=B.Value WHERE A.Value IS NULL OR B.Value IS NULL
```

Comment: i am getting error like "RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOINs are not currently supported" and sqlite version is 3.9.1

Comment: RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOINs are really not supported in SQLite and it will be done using LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
select [list] from Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 on Table1.columnA=Table2.columnA where Table2.columnA IS NULL
UNION
select [list] from Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 on Table2.columnA=Table1.columnA where Table1.columnA IS NULL
```

Comment: above code is true but i want only table1 columns and also table2.date = this month like '04'

Comment: use this code (select [list] from Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 on Table1.columnA=Table2.columnA where Table2.columnA IS NULL and Table2.date between '2016-04-01' and '2016-04-30')

Comment: but i want table2.date equal to month format(04) only.

Comment: I applied your code  (Table2.date between '2016-04-01' and '2016-04-30') but no result. But two records exists in Table2.date is '2016-04-09'.

Comment: I think you need UNION ALL

Comment: I didn't check the answer above, but in any case you should use UNION ALL, not UNION

Answer (score 0):

Hi everybody
 thanks for all your answers & support. 
I got the solution,the code is

**select [columns] from Table1 where not exists (select * from Table2 where Table2.A = Table1.A and strftime('%m', Table2.date)='04')**